# Invalid form for default selected option in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

I have the following form in VueJs 2

```
<form id="trial-form" action="post" class="trial">
    <div class="form-field required selectbox">
        <select name="region" id="region" label="region" v-validate="'required'" v-model="region" class="required selectbox region" aria-label="Region">
            <option value="">{{ $t("region") }}</option>
            <p-option v-for="regionOption in regionList" :key="regionOption.region" :value="regionOption.plane">{{$t(regionOption.region)}}</p-option>
        </select>
        <p-button size="lrg" align="left" type="submit" :disabled="isFormInvalid" @click.prevent="validateBeforeSubmit">{{ $t("trialSubmit") }}</p-button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am setting the `v-model` hardcoded and the code is as follows:

```
mounted () {
  this.region = 'US'
}
```

This sets the US as selected in the select box. My validation function is as follows:

```
computed: {
    isFormInvalid () {
      return Object.keys(this.fields).some(key => this.fields[key].invalid)
    }
  }
```

Now even though the value in the select dropdown is shown as selected by default, the submit button is not activated. If I change the select options, then the button is activated and I am able to submit the form. As the select box is showing as selected by default, user should be able to submit without selecting it manually. What is wrong here ? Thanks in advance

Comment: `v-validate` is from using "VeeValidate"? Shouldn't the rule also refer to the data? Like this: `v-validate="'required|region'"`. See [v-validate docs](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/api/directive.html#directive-args).

Comment: If I give that it is showing `Error: [vee-validate] No such validator 'region' exists` error. The only issue here is that the select box is selected by default and it is showing the value as selected, but the submit button is not enabled.

Comment: Oh I misread the docs I believe. Try this: `v-validate:region="'required'"`. It should work with an existing v-model. `region` comes from your `data`? Or should `this.fields.region` be used directly?

Comment: @HappyCoder I added an answer with 2 solution ideas. Please check it out, I hope it will work as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

To validate the field as soon as the page loads, You should use directive modifier [`.immediate`](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/api/directive.html#immediate)

```
<select name="region" id="region" v-validate.immediate="'required'" v-model="region">
```

Or other workaround solution is just to check if v-model contains a value or not and returns `boolean` value by using a computed property and add a `errors.any()` along with this computed property for a more robust solution.

In Script **:**

```
computed: {
  isFormInvalid () {
    return !this.region;
  }
}
```

In Template **:**

```
<p-button type="submit" :disabled="errors.any() || isFormInvalid" @click.prevent="validateBeforeSubmit">{{ $t("trialSubmit") }}</p-button>
```

Comment: I have other elements also there in the form. How can I use the computed function if there are multiple form elements ? I need to check whether each of them is valid. Just added the one element that I am facing issue with.

Comment: I know this is not good code, but I ended up doing `if (this.region) {this.fields['region'].invalid = false }  return this.fields[key].invalid`

Comment: @HappyCoder In the case where you have multiple form elements. Did you tried my first suggestion with `.immediate` directive modifier.